minimum height to a chart
I have made a bar char which have two columns per category. Does anyone know how to set a minimum height for column?
I wanted it to have a minimum pixel height in value as sometimes the data varies and you can only see very little of the value depending on how it is rendered on the ranges.

Question isn't currently clear but you can use a clamp expression to always have a minimum

Hi @davidebacci I was asking if we can add a minimum pixel height to the columns for example if the value is too small e.g. 0.01, it would barely show in the chart

You could add an additional transform like this:
{"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.value2 < 0 && datum.value2 > -1 ? -1: datum.value2 > 0 && datum.value2 < 1 ? 1: datum.value2", "as": "value2"}

So:
If the value is between -1 and 0 then it will be: -1
If the value is between 0 and 1 it will be: 1
Also add a note at the bottom of the chart because it can be misleading:)

Thanks for the above. From what I understand, whatever the value passed already being rendered as pixel? So I guess if I have values that are not zero, I can just set them to value + 2?

@coralinecodes please mark the answer as solved if this helped you.
